# How do I fscanf a file and store the data on the line in different variables depending on the first character of the line?

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have a file with data, here is a sample of the data:

> ```
> S:BMW;328i;A8;2.0
> S:GMC;K1500 SIERRA 4X4;A4;5.3
> C:SUBCOMPACT;M5;X
> C:PICKUP TRUCK;A4;X
> ```

I want to scan the first character on the line and store the data at `A`

If A is an `'S'`, I want to store the remaining data on the line at `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`

If A is a `'C'`, I want to store the remaining data on the line at `F`, `G`, `H`

How do I do this for every line in this file?

This is how I did it for another file where each line had the same format:

```
int currentSize = 0;
while(fscanf(fp, "%d,%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%f,%[^,],%c,%f,%f,%f,%f", &data[currentSize].year, &data[currentSize].make, &data[currentSize].model, 
        &data[currentSize].type, &data[currentSize].engineSize, &data[currentSize].transmissionType, &data[currentSize].fuelType, &data[currentSize].city, 
        &data[currentSize].hwy, &data[currentSize].fuelPerYear, &data[currentSize].co2) != EOF) {
    currentSize++;
}
return currentSize;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fgets()` to get the content of each line, then use `sscanf()` to get each field depending on the first character:

```
char line[MAX_CHAR];
while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
{
    switch(line[0])
    {
        case 'S': 
            //process line using sscanf()
            break;
        case 'C':
            //process line using sscanf()
            break;
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3211391 Note: Be sure to test the result of `sscanf()` against the number of expected fields that should have been scanned and not ` != EOF`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider taking just the first letter first, then the rest with seperate `fscanf`s:

```
// notice the space behind %c
while ( fscanf( " %c", &A ) == 1 ) {
    if ( A == 'S' && fscanf( ":%[^;];%[^;];%[^;];%f", B, C, D, &E ) == 4 ) {

        // do whatever with them

    }
    if ( A == 'C' && fscanf( ":%[^;];%[^;];%c", F, G, &H ) == 3 ) {

        // do whatever with them

    }
```

When the first operand of the logical and operator `&&` is wrong, the second one is defined to not get operator.